# MySQL replication by choice with custom data formatting

Tags: mysql, caching, replication, database-replication, data-formatters

Is it possible to replicate a mysql database by choosing only the tables you want to be replicated (unto the target database) considering the target database has a slightly different structure.

Consider the following:

I have a database loaded with all the data I need to be replicated to the target database. Let's call this our `MasterDatabase`

Now I have the `TargetDatabase` this is a lite version of the `MasterDatabase` and will be used will be used for the presentation layer. Note that the two database have tables with different structures.

Is replication possible in this scenario?

If not, is there a solution to update the data on the `TargetDatabase` from the `MasterDatabase` without doing massive updates maybe selective updates just as a normal replication would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication is somewhat flexible in the sense you can [replicate to different storage engines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-solutions-diffengines.html), and yes, even [selectively choose the data you want replicated](http://crazytoon.com/2008/04/21/mysql-replication-replicate-by-choice/).

Keep in mind though that replication is meant to be an identical copy of your source dataset.  If you need different formats or different table definitions in your schema, it is not really data replication anymore.

Comment: is replication in MySQL realtime?

Comment: MySQL replication is fast which means in average delay is small. Typically microseconds. However if there happens to be some bulk query on the master, even on completely unrelated table, replication lag may increase dramatically.

Comment: If you are diving in replication, I recommend you read through [chapter 15 of the mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html). Precious information in there on the configuration options _and_ the gotchas you may face.